# Why does this simple MySQL procedure take way too long to complete?

Tags: mysql, database

This is a very simple MySQL stored procedure. Cursor "commission" has only 3000 records, but the procedure call takes more than 30 seconds to run. Why is that?

```
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS apply_credit//

CREATE PROCEDURE apply_credit()
BEGIN

  DECLARE done tinyint DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE _pk_id INT;
  DECLARE _eid, _source VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE _lh_revenue, _acc_revenue, _project_carrier_expense, _carrier_lh, _carrier_acc, _gross_margin, _fsc_revenue, _revenue, _load_count DECIMAL;

  DECLARE commission CURSOR FOR
    SELECT pk_id, eid, source, lh_revenue, acc_revenue, project_carrier_expense, carrier_lh, carrier_acc, gross_margin, fsc_revenue, revenue, load_count FROM ct_sales_commission;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  DELETE FROM debug;

  OPEN commission;

  REPEAT
    FETCH commission INTO
      _pk_id, _eid, _source, _lh_revenue, _acc_revenue, _project_carrier_expense, _carrier_lh, _carrier_acc, _gross_margin, _fsc_revenue, _revenue, _load_count;
    INSERT INTO debug VALUES(concat('row ', _pk_id));

  UNTIL done = 1 END REPEAT;

  CLOSE commission;

END//

DELIMITER ;
CALL apply_credit();
SELECT * FROM debug;
```

Comment: Can you please provide DB schema with indexes?

Comment: Run both queries (`DELETE FROM debug` and your `SELECT`) on a direct session and time it, report back.

Comment: Thank you Adrian and Eugen. ct_sales_commission is a simple table with one index on 'pk_id'. `delete from debug` and `select * from ct_sales_commission` take less than 2 second to run.

Comment: @HowardGuo You can edit your answer to provide the extra info a usual style is to add an EDIT keyword in bold and then place the extra info - people do not always read the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is hosted in a data centre very far away from my MySQL client.

Connected to a MySQL client which is closely located with the MySQL server makes execution time almost 60 times faster (it takes less than one second for the procedure to complete).

I suspect that MySQL client CLI has an issue handling a remote data connection like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you select some datas, and insert into another table, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO debug 
SELECT concat('row ', _pk_id)
FROM ct_sales_commission;
```

It's faster than using a cursor.

---

Some minor turning:

- Remove all indexes on the table `debug`.
- Replace the `DELETE FROM` into `TRUNCATE TABLE`.
- Add `DELAYED` to the insert statement.

  ```
  INSERT DELAYED INTO ... VALUES(....)
  ```

Comment: Thank you Mike, but I was planning to do something to the fetched values.